# bash myscript.sh runs in bash, but the first line is #!/usr/bin/sh

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, solaris

I have a script similar following one:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

var="ABC"
if [ $var == "ABC" ]
then
   echo True
else
   echo False
fi
```

Above code does not work in Solaris Sparc and Solaris X64. It is showing `==` undefined. 
Above code works fine If I replace `==` with `=`.

Strange thing is If I ran above code without any change by following method it is working.

```
#bash test.sh
```

According to my understanding the script should not work even with bash, as at the top of the script I am using `#!/bin/sh` which does not support the `==`  as the comparison operator.

Can anyone please explain why it does work when I am running the script as mentioned above.

Note: I am aware of that bash does recognize `==` and `=`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first line of the script is called the `#!` line (sometimes called the ["shebang"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line).

It is only used when a script is executed directly, as in

```
./test.sh
```

**Explanation**

When you run an executable, the operating system looks at the first two bytes to tell what type of program it is.

When you run

```
./test.sh
```

the operating system sees that the first two bytes of `./test.sh` are `#!`, so it knows the program is a script.

It reads the rest of the line to see which shell<sup>1</sup> it should use to run the script.  In this case, the rest of the line is `/usr/bin/sh`, so it runs `/usr/bin/sh test.sh`<sup>2</sup>.

When you run

```
bash test.sh
```

it finds bash in `/usr/bin/bash`<sup>3</sup>.  It sees that the first two bytes of `/usr/bin/bash` are not `#!`, so it runs `/usr/bin/bash test.sh` without even looking at the first line of `test.sh.`

In both cases, `sh` and `bash` actually ignore the shebang line because any line beginning with `#` is a comment.  The `#` only has this magic effect because of the operating system, not the shell.

More info:

- [#!](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/std/hashexclam-1.html)
- [The Whole Story on #! /usr/bin/ksh](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/36711-whole-story-usr-bin-ksh.html)
- [Solaris execve man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=execve&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS+5.9&arch=default&format=html)
- [Linux execve man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Footnotes:

1. In fact, it can be any program, it doesn't have to be a shell.
2. Actually more like `execl("./test.sh", "/usr/bin/sh", "./test.sh", NULL)`.
3. `/bin/sh` on most Linux systems, but the question was about Solaris.

Answer (score 6):

Running the script with bash (running `bash test.sh`) means that the script is interpreted with bash, not the Bourne shell (/bin/sh).  That's why it works.  Bash ignores the #!/bin/sh because it is a comment.  It's only your [OS's program loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) that starts /bin/sh if you run the shell script without bash (running `./test.sh` for example).