# Debug messages on function

Tags: bash, shell-script, debugging

I need a function to show, only during debug, a message (the function name):

```
#!/bin/bash

debug_function(){
  if [[ $DEBUG -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "${FUNCNAME[1]}"
  else
    DEBUG=0
  fi
}

test_function(){
 debug_function
 echo "something"
}

foo=$(test_function)

echo "Result: $foo"
```

It works, but in DEBUG=1 the function name is added to function output obviously.

```
# sh test
Result: something

# DEBUG=1 sh test
Result: test_function
something
```

Is there a way to print only a message?

Using `wall` I get the right behavior, but are there some other alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: Note when you run `sh test` the shebang is totally irrelevant (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45048/108618)). Pure `sh` cannot run your code. Your `sh` apparently can, but this is "accidental". The code is for `bash` and the shebang looks right. Make the file executable and run it as `./test`.

Comment: Totally right, just for test I din't set +x on script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `echo "${FUNCNAME[1]}"` prints to stdout, so its output belongs to the output of the `debug_function`, which in turn belongs to the output of the `test_function`.

Print the message to stderr:

- by redirecting the output of `echo`:

  ```
  echo "${FUNCNAME[1]}" >&2
  ```
- or by redirecting the entire output of `debug_function` (if the whole function should print only to stderr) when you call `debug_function`:

  ```
  debug_function >&2
  ```

The latter method allows commands inside the `debug_function` to print straightforwardly to stdout. What they print will be redirected because stdout of the `debug_function` is redirected.

The function itself can redirect its stdout to its stderr with `exec >&2`. This will affect all commands in the function. But this will also affect the calling function/script, unless the redirecting function is run in a subshell.

You can run the function in a subshell on demand with `(debug_function)`. To always run the function in a subshell, use `()` instead of `{}` when defining the function.

So a function whose entire purpose is to print to stderr and not to stdout can be defined like:

```bsh
debug_function()(
   exec >&2
   echo whatever
   # ...
)
```

Now `echo` and other commands in the function don't need `>&2`. Even if you call the function simply as `debug_function`, the commands in it will print to stderr.

<sup>Note: stdout or stderr of one subshell or command can be different than stdout or stderr of another subshell or command or the script as a whole. Redirections are possible on many levels. Therefore even a function that does `exec >&2` in its own subshell can ultimately write to stdout of the whole script, if "proper" redirections happen outside of the function body. I won't elaborate.</sup>

The most important thing to remember:

Stdout is often captured (like in your case) or piped further. The main point of stderr is [not to let error/debug/diagnostic messages pollute stdout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79333/108618).

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I need. I didn't think (also because I din't know) to run function in a subshell.